# UISearchbar and PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, pfquery, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I am using `PFQueryTableViewController` and `UISearchBar`. I am not using `UISearchBarDisplayController`. The underlying query is only searching when I write the search string either in lowercase or uppercase. I want to use both. Either you write in lower case or uppercase, it will search. This is my piece of code.

```
-(PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
 PFQuery *query;
 if (self.canSearch == 0) {
 query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
 } else {
 query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
 //This is searchbar text.
 //NSString *searchThis = [_searchbar.text upercaseString];
 NSString *searchThis = [_searchbar.text lowercaseString];
 [query whereKey:@"username" containsString:searchThis];
 }
 [query orderByAscending:@"username"];
 // If Pull To Refresh is enabled, query against the network by default.
 if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
  }
// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the   table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
if (self.objects.count == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
 } 
 return query;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    // Use cached facebook friend ids
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"Useridentifier" matchesRegex:searchBar_User.text];

    PFQuery *query1 = [PFUser query];
    [query1 whereKey:@"displayName" matchesRegex:searchBar_User.text];


    PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query, query1]];
    userQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;

    if (self.objects.count == 0)
    {
        userQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }
    [userQuery orderByAscending:kPAPUserDisplayNameKey];
    return userQuery;

    return query;
}
```

hello You cant Manage This by Variable You just Show my Code Below

I think this code is very Helpful for you...

Comment: Hi Anand. Welcome to StackOverflow! You may want to edit your answer to make it more clear. The first and last lines of your answer should be outside of the code block. Remove the four spaces at the beginning of the first and last lines so they don't show up as being part of the code.

Comment: @vasim I m not New in stackoverflow i have Already 2000 Reputation. but I lost my Account..